# Coldfusion 10 Flash Remoting deserializing Error

Tags: flash, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Our Coldfusion 10 Standard server (Windows 2008 and IIS7) has been handling flash remoting requests from our Flex app and AIR IOS, AIR Android APP sweetly for over a year until a few days ago.

We're now getting frequent errors of the type:

```
REMOTEOBJECT ERROR Client.Packet.Encoding Error deserializing client message. null
```

when sending a VO to a coldfusion CFC as follows:

```
mainApp.routeRemoteCall('lessonService','recordLesson'{aLessonVO:myLesson,runIte:runIte},this)
```

and cfc:

```
<cffunction name="recordLesson" access="remote" returntype="String">
<cfargument name="aLessonVO" type="appcfc.cfcs.LessonVO">
<cfargument name="runITE" type="boolean" >
```

etc etc

We've made no code changes on the server or apps to trigger this. We've restarted the server.
The errors are intermittent and distributed across users. 
Typically you get an error when you start a session of use then it resolves.

Errors are more common when more users are connected - as you always expect  - however this could indicate a scale issue.
Regarding scale, we would only have max 50 or so users using the apps at one time.